# How to share my notebook

Tags: notebooks

Of course there are some method can do this. Such as the Uploader or the inbuilt function of `CloudPublish` all can do this. But I want to use my method. For specify this question, I make a temporary `.nb` file, you can get it by this code:

```
NotebookPut[(Uncompress@*FromCharacterCode@*
    Flatten@*(ImageData[#1, "Byte"] &)@*Import)[
  "http://ooo.0o0.ooo/2016/10/24/580dc3a67b252.png"]]
```

#### Current method:

If I wanto share this `.nb` file.I will use [my custom function `ShareAny` here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2005/21532):

```
NotebookPut[
 ShareAny[Get[
   NotebookSave[
    InputNotebook[], $TemporaryDirectory <> 
     "tem.nb"]; $TemporaryDirectory <> "tem.nb"]]]
```

Then I will get the share expresion like:

> NotebookPut[(Uncompress@*FromCharacterCode@*Flatten@*(ImageData[#1,"Byte"]&)@*Import)["http://ooo.0o0.ooo/2016/10/24/580dc359c503b.png"]]

#### Question:

The notebook to share will include the expression:
[image]

- I hope it cann't include this expression.
- I very don't like using that `NotebookSave` to make a temporary files, I think it will make some waste.

Any method can help to improve this method?

---

The first question seem to be solved by [Mr. Alexey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129512/21532).As his answer,we can just use

```
NotebookPut[ShareAny[NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]]]]
```

to share our current notebook.But the second question still.The notebook to share include the last code like:

[image]

Any method can avoid it?It seem we should delete the last `CellGroupData` from `NotebookGet`.

Comment: Instead of `Get[NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], ...]]` you could simply use `NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Wow,I don't know this before.Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Get[NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], ...]]` you should simply use `NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]]`. If you don't want to have this expression in the shared copy of the Notebook, you could replace `InputNotebook` with `SelectedNotebook` and make a Palette with a button which will copy to Clipboard the output of `ShareAny`:

```
CreatePalette@
 Button["Share Notebook", CopyToClipboard@ShareAny[NotebookGet[SelectedNotebook[]]]]
```

Comment: But It include the last code still.?

Comment: @yode I updated the answer.

Comment: It seem we should delete the last `Cell[CellGroupData[...]]` from `NotebookGet` I think.

Comment: @yodeling It is possible but the straightforward way is to make a Palette and run the code from it.